# React build select input using for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to build a Select dropdown and populate the input fields using a for loop.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    let options = [];
    for (let i=2; i < 20.5; i += 0.5){
      options.push(<option value={i*60} key={i}>{i} hours</option>)
    }
    return (
      <select>
        {options}
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

The `{i} hours` section causes an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` error message. Changing it to a fixed string prevents the error.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic but I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Works for me, usually the 'props' of undefined issue is with a this binding - is there more code somewhere?

Comment: I thought it may have been some other code but I made this test component and render it directly to the page using the code below and it still occurs:
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Test), document.querySelector('.react-container'));

Comment: A Jsfiddle would help :)

Comment: dont use React.createElement for es6 classes, just render the JSX ie ReactDom.render(<Test />, document.querySelector('.react-container')); createElement should only be used w/ components created with createClass

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I only used it for the purposes of this test to completely isolate this snippet from the rest of my code.

Comment: Sigh, it doesn't seem to occur in a jsfiddle. I have no idea what could be causing it especially after I set it up in a test project with no other code :( https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: oops wrong link https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/33076/

Comment: so does the error still happen when you get rid of createElement invocations for es6 classes?

Comment: Yep, still occurring with: ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector('.react-container'));

Comment: I dont see any error in the fiddle. Still same?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, it doesn't occur in the fiddle but the exact same code has the error when run locally. I'm completely stumped as to the cause

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    const options = [];
    for (let i=2; i < 20.5; i += 0.5) options.push(i);
    return (
      <select>
        {options.map(option => (
          <option key={option} value={option*60}>
            {option} hours
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

or (in 2021) as a function component:

```
export default const Test = () => {
  const options = [];
  for (let i=2;i<20.5;i+=0.5) options.push(i);
  return (
    <select>
      {options.map(option => (
        <option key={option} value={option*60}>
          {option} hours
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  )
}
```